# Help Identify the brand of a guitar

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

I purchased a new guitar just recently. Am not able to identify the brand and it has no stickers inside to figure out. Am hoping with the pictures and markings someone can help with that.

Thank you

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: The M markings will be the manufacturer logo of the company that made the machine heads, so won’t help identifying the actual guitar.

Comment: Did you already ask in this shop: https://www.hours.be/muziekparadijs/kalmthout/1

Comment: I figured that is where the guitar came from or was serviced since the sticker was on but it turns out they are not in business anymore. https://www.gva.be/cnt/aid717535/muziekparadijs-sluit-de-deuren

Comment: I found the closing down notice from 08, but why do their business hours still show?

Comment: I guess theny did not notify the classifieds

Comment: The Made in GDR sticker implies that this is an East German guitar. I found the following link with a list of East German guitar manufacturers: http://www.blackrabbitinstruments.com/GermanGuitarGuide.html

Comment: 12 string, eh? How does it sound, and play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit more research and I'm pretty confident that this is a Musima (East German) guitar since the stylized M on the tuners matches the logo of that manufacturer, plus the Made in GDR sticker indicates that it's an East German guitar.

Answer (score 3):

Closest I can find is a Musima Western 12 string - Made in Germany in the 1980s. No match on the fingerboard inlays or the roundel, though.

The attached images are all from https://www.vintageandrare.com/product/Musima-Western-1984-Natural-46834#prettyPhoto

[image: Headstock Back]
[image: Headstock Front]
[image: Body]
[image: Complete Guitar]